# Grails and charting?

Tags: grails, charts, grails-plugin

I am wondering about the best current charting solution for Grails to include charts in my pages.  Looking at the Flex plugin, it doesnt look like it has been touched in a couple of years.  There are google charts (and eastwood) plugins but they are a bit too simple for what I am looking for.  Just checking if I am missing something.

Comment: Without knowing your specific application or needs, there's no useful way someone could answer "the best plugin".  As cdeszaq mentioned below, there's at least 5 charting plugins.  And this doesn't include the literally dozens of JS-based charting libraries.  [Please see the StackOverflow FAQ for more on what questions are appropriate.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of [Grails plugins](http://grails.org/plugins/) that deal with charting and allow integrating with well-respected methods of generating charts and graphs.

From just a quick search for "charts", some of the ones I recognized are:

- [Google Chart Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/google-chart)
- [Google Visualization API Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/google-visualization)
- [OpenFlash Charting](http://grails.org/plugin/ofchart)
- [Sparklines Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/sparklines)
- [Raphael for Grails](http://grails.org/plugin/raphael)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a JavaScript solution, [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/) is the most sophisticated charting library I've seen. It's free for non-commercial use only.

Answer (score 0):

Try the dojo plugin. Look for dojox.charting on google.