# Display bar graph using export plugin in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, graph, export

I have sample data which I want to show in bar/pie graph using export plugin in grails. I googled a lot but was unable to get exact details of how to do it?

Can anybody please provide me links or any information to start off with this? Thank you.

Comment: The export plugin does not support graphs. If you need to create graphs in excel files you will need to write your own routines using something like Apache POI.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, up voted. can you please provide some stuffs which can take me to create bar graph in pdf?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide much description about exactly what your use case is but there are a number of charting plugins for Grails mentioned in this question:

[Grails and charting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082412/grails-and-charting)

These plugins would enable you to render charts on your page. Then there's the issue of converting to PDF. Is it acceptable for users to print the web page to PDF using the browser's functionality? If not, again there are plugins for converting GSPs to PDF (such as http://grails.org/plugin/pdf).

Hopefully you should be able to do what you want with a combination of plugins.